# C# OpenSSL to achieve TLS1.2 in .Net Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, openssl, .net-2.0, tls1.2

I have requirement to achieve TLS1.2 in .Net framework 4.0 using OpenSSL.

I searched a lot for same but unable to find the code snippet for use of  OpenSSL to set TLS1.2 security protocol instead of existing way OR another possible way of adding OpenSSL into it

My requirement is:

1. Communicate to our web service using TLS1.2 (Send request and read response from web service)
2. We can not upgrade machines to .Net framework 4.5, they have framework .Net 4.0

Current code implementation is as below where we are allowed/have .Net framework 4.0 and above

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strHostUrl);
            request.Method = "POST";                
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.UserAgent = "Java/1.7.0_51";
            request.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            request.Timeout = intTimeoutInMS;
            request.ReadWriteTimeout = 3000;
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)192 | (SecurityProtocolType)768 | (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

We are seeing for option of using OpenSSL to achieve TLS1.2.

Is it possible to achieve the same? Can anyone please provide some help on above question.

Comment: @rene Thanks for you comment. We have already tried both options and it is failing to set Security Protocol Tls1.2 also upgrade to .Net4.5 is not possible so we are looking for use of OpenSSL to set the Security Protocol in above code. Is it possible to use OpenSSL through any Nuget Package available and anyone used it already.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't magically inject OpenSSL in the network stack. But if you're open to use [curl](https://www.nuget.org/packages/curl/) instead of the built-in (Http)WebRequest classes you get OpenSSL as a dependency so that might work out well for you. You should be able to do with curl what you have done now with the HttpWebRequest.

Comment: One other thing: Did youset the SecurityProtocol **before** you call WebRequest.Create? Setting the securityprotocol *after* you established a servicepoint is kind of useless and that might not rectify itself as those are cached, IIRC. Your code example kind of indicates that and I didn't notice it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Now I have made that change in .net framework 3.5. Please download OpenSSL wrapper (1.0.2 a) and above and include that project to your solution and follow the below link. https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/