# AWS 'Amazon MQ' - Rabbit MQ error: The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, rabbitmq, iis-8, windows-server-2012

I implemented a connection to my aws rabbit mq service with the c# RabbitMQ.Client.
This connection works very well on my local machine. But when i publish my app to my iis server, running on Windows 2012 i get following exception:

```
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm
```

I checked my TLS versions on my win machine with IIS Crypto and installes TLS1.2 but without any result
[image]

Also i tried every available setting combination on my ConnectionFactory, without any result. Latest version:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol |= SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
new ConnectionFactory()
{
  Uri = new Uri($"amqps://{User}:{Password}@{Hostname}:{Port}/{VirtualHost}"),
  Ssl = new SslOption
  {
    CertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true,
    Enabled = true,
    Version = SslProtocols.Tls12,
    ServerName = Hostname,
    AcceptablePolicyErrors = SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors |
                                           
    SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch |
                                             
    SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable,
  }
};
```

Someone can help me to fix this problem?

Also tried this solutions:
[TLS 1. 2 The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54748329/tls-1-2-the-client-and-server-cannot-communicate-because-they-do-not-possess-a)

My Setup:

1. C# .Net 5
2. IIS 8
3. RabbitMQ.Client 6.5.0
4. Windows Server 2012

Full Exception:

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException
None of the specified endpoints were reachable
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Authentication failed, see inner exception.)
 ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication failed, see inner exception.
 ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80090331): Der Client und der Server können keine Daten austauschen, da sie nicht über einen gemeinsamen Algorithmus verfügen.
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<TcpUpgrade>b__0(SslOption opts)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SslHelper.TcpUpgrade(Stream tcpStream, SslOption options)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SocketFrameHandler..ctor(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.IProtocolExtensions.CreateFrameHandler(IProtocol protocol, AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint, ArrayPool`1 pool, Func`2 socketFactory, TimeSpan connectionTimeout, TimeSpan readTimeout, TimeSpan writeTimeout)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateFrameHandler(AmqpTcpEndpoint endpoint)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at RabbitMQ.Client.EndpointResolverExtensions.SelectOne[T](IEndpointResolver resolver, Func`2 selector)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(IEndpointResolver endpoints)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(IEndpointResolver endpointResolver, String clientProvidedName)
 at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(String clientProvidedName)\r\n   at RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection()
 at AlfaTools.Interface.RabbitMQ.RabbitMQService..ctor(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) in C:\\Users\\Kevve\\Github\\alfatools-backend\\AlfaTools.Interface.RabbitMQ\\RabbitMQService.cs:line 96
 at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
 at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
 at lambda_method4145(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
```

Comment: SSL is obsolete.  Only TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 are valid.  Error is probably due to the certificate.  The certificate has an encryption mode and the encryption mode may only be supported in TLS 1.3.  Your application does not support TLS 1.3 (only TLS 1.2).  See Wiki for more info : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: Download latest Nartac which supports TLS 1.3 : https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download

Comment: The issue was Windows Server 2012. Same code working on a newer machine like WS 2019

Comment: The SSL certificate has an encryption mode and older machines do not support many of the older encryption modes.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security there are solutions using OpenSSL.  You may be able to upgrade following code to work on a 2012 server https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47887685/c-sharp-openssl-to-achieve-tls1-2-in-net-framework-4-0